# Map step function result and extract certain keys

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have the following output coming from a step function task: ListObjectsV2

```json
{
  "Contents": [
    {
      "ETag": "\"86c12c034bc6c30cb89b500b954c188f\"",
      "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_1.csv",
      "LastModified": "2023-02-09T13:46:20Z",
      "Size": 796014,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "ETag": "\"58e4a770e0f66073b00d185df500f07f\"",
      "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_2.csv",
      "LastModified": "2023-02-09T13:47:20Z",
      "Size": 934038,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "ETag": "\"460abd0de64d5cb67e8f0d46878cb1ef\"",
      "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_3.csv",
      "LastModified": "2023-02-09T13:46:57Z",
      "Size": 794264,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "ETag": "\"1bfedc3dc92e4ba8d04e24b9b5a0ed58\"",
      "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_4.csv",
      "LastModified": "2023-02-09T13:46:24Z",
      "Size": 788756,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    },
    {
      "ETag": "\"9d6c434ce5ebdf203a790fbcf19338dc\"",
      "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_5.csv",
      "LastModified": "2023-02-09T13:47:07Z",
      "Size": 831156,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
    }
  ],
  "IsTruncated": false,
  "KeyCount": 5,
  "MaxKeys": 1000,
  "Name": "vita-internal-text-classification-dev-183576513728",
  "Prefix": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157"
}
```

I want to have an array containing only the `Key` key, to pass to the next state, like so:

```json
[
    {
        "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_1.csv",
    },
    {
        "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_2.csv",
    },
    {
        "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_3.csv",
    },
    {
        "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_4.csv",
    },
    {
        "Key": "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_5.csv",
    }
]
```

So far I've tried setting the ResultPath to:

$.Contents[*].Key

$.Contents[*].['Key']

What I get is:

```json
  [
    "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_1.csv",
    "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_2.csv",
    "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_3.csv",
    "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_4.csv",
    "55271f52fffe4461a2ee3228ebb97157/input/batch_5.csv",
  ]
```

But I've gotten bad output from that, any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the "bad output" from the variants you tried.

Comment: `Map` State + `Pass` State, of course. I don't know if there's a one-shot JSONPath solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've solved this is to use an Inline Map state with a Pass state to build the necessary format. You can see this pattern in an example here for how to use [Step Functions Distributed Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html) to [bulk delete objects from S3](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/blob/main/sam/demo-bulk-delete-s3-objects/bulk-delete-objects-from-s3.asl.json). You can see this in the inner `Create Object Identifier Array` Map state. If you were doing this in Standard Workflows, this could be a cost concern given the number of state transitions involved. But since in the Item Processor I'm using [Express Workflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-standard-vs-express.html), which are billed by duration (and these are super fast), it works pretty well.

[image]

```
{
  "Comment": "A state machine to bulk delete objects from S3 using Distributed Map",
  "StartAt": "Confirm Bucket Provided",
  "States": {
    "Confirm Bucket Provided": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Not": {
            "Variable": "$.bucket",
            "IsPresent": true
          },
          "Next": "Fail - No Bucket"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Check for Prefix"
    },
    "Check for Prefix": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Not": {
            "Variable": "$.prefix",
            "IsPresent": true
          },
          "Next": "Generate Parameters - Without Prefix"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Generate Parameters - With Prefix"
    },
    "Generate Parameters - Without Prefix": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "Bucket.$": "$.bucket",
        "Prefix": ""
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.list_parameters",
      "Next": "Delete Objects from S3 Bucket"
    },
    "Fail - No Bucket": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "InsuffcientArguments",
      "Cause": "No Bucket was provided"
    },
    "Generate Parameters - With Prefix": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "Delete Objects from S3 Bucket",
      "Parameters": {
        "Bucket.$": "$.bucket",
        "Prefix.$": "$.prefix"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.list_parameters"
    },
    "Delete Objects from S3 Bucket": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "EXPRESS"
        },
        "StartAt": "Create Object Identifier Array",
        "States": {
          "Create Object Identifier Array": {
            "Type": "Map",
            "ItemProcessor": {
              "ProcessorConfig": {
                "Mode": "INLINE"
              },
              "StartAt": "Create Object Identifier",
              "States": {
                "Create Object Identifier": {
                  "Type": "Pass",
                  "End": true,
                  "Parameters": {
                    "Key.$": "$.Key"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "ItemsPath": "$.Items",
            "ResultPath": "$.object_identifiers",
            "Next": "Delete Objects"
          },
          "Delete Objects": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Next": "Clear Output",
            "Parameters": {
              "Bucket.$": "$.BatchInput.bucket",
              "Delete": {
                "Objects.$": "$.object_identifiers"
              }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:deleteObjects",
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.ALL"
                ],
                "BackoffRate": 2,
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "MaxAttempts": 6
              }
            ],
            "ResultSelector": {
              "Deleted.$": "$.Deleted",
              "RetryCount.$": "$$.State.RetryCount"
            }
          },
          "Clear Output": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true,
            "Result": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "ItemReader": {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:listObjectsV2",
        "Parameters": {
          "Bucket.$": "$.list_parameters.Bucket",
          "Prefix.$": "$.list_parameters.Prefix"
        }
      },
      "MaxConcurrency": 5,
      "Label": "S3objectkeys",
      "ItemBatcher": {
        "MaxInputBytesPerBatch": 204800,
        "MaxItemsPerBatch": 1000,
        "BatchInput": {
          "bucket.$": "$.list_parameters.Bucket"
        }
      },
      "ResultSelector": {},
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin thank you for your answer and example.
We are also working on S3 deletion in a Step Function flow, and we are debating whether to use your example, or a lambda with boto3.
What would you recommend? 
your solution is quite complicated, do you see any advantage using it, rather to a simple lambda?

Comment: I'd have to know more about your specifics, but I believe this solution is likely to be the more robust one. If you were just going to sequentially iterate through objects in an S3 bucket and delete, then a Lambda function would be a simple way to do so (for a small bucket). But I don't think you'll find a simpler way to achieve this level of parallelism with built in observabilty and control. Which you'll need for larger buckets. Plus, with Step Function, you never need to worry about upgrading runtimes and dependencies, so it tends to be simpler in the long run.

Comment: As for the need to use the Map state to format the output, in this particular case I see it as unfortunately complexity that one has to figure out to get it working, but it won't add complexity over time. I hope this answer will help others with a similar need. At the same time, we are looking at ways to make the sort of transformation you described simpler in Step Functions. So I hope one day to come back to this answer with an update for something even simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Recently, we had the same issue in AWS Step functions while trying to list objects of a bucket and using the list to delete them in the next step.

After fetching the list of objects running an AWS API call step:

```
tasks.CallAwsService(
            self,
            f"list-s3-objects-{bucket}-{prefix}",
            service="s3",
            action="listObjects",
            parameters={
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Prefix": prefix,
            },
            iam_resources=["*"],
            result_path="$.s3_object_list",
        )
```

The following JsonPath expression worked to feed the object list for deletion:

```
tasks.CallAwsService(
            self,
            f"delete-s3-objects-{bucket}",
            service="s3",
            action="deleteObjects",
            parameters={
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Delete": {"Objects": sfn.JsonPath.list_at("$.s3_object_list.Contents[*].['Key','VersionId']"
        )Ï},
            },
            iam_resources=["*"],
            result_path=sfn.JsonPath.DISCARD,
        )
```

The key part is the following JsonPath:

```
Contents[*].['Key','VersionId']"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Where is the `VersionId` field from?